# How is this O(1) space and not O(n) space. firstNotRepeatingCharacter Challenge solution

Tags: javascript, big-o

I am having trouble understanding how the following solution is O(1) space and not O(n) space.  The coding challenge is as follows:

*Write a solution that only iterates over the string once and uses O(1) additional memory, since this is what you would be asked to do during a real interview.*

Given a string s, find and return the first instance of a non-repeating character in it. If there is no such character then return '_'.

The following is a solution that is O(1) space.

```html
function firstNotRepeatingCharacters(s: string) : string {
    const chars: string[] = s.split('');
    let duplicates = {};
    let answer = '_';
    let indexAnswer = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

    chars.forEach((element, index) => {
        if(!duplicates.hasOwnProperty(element)) {
            duplicates[element] = {
                count: 1,
                index
            }
        } else {
            duplicates[element].count++;
            duplicates[element].index = index;
        }
    });

    for(const key in duplicates) {
        if(duplicates[key].count === 1 && duplicates[key].index < indexAnswer) {
            answer = key;
            indexAnswer = duplicates[key].index;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter('abacabad'));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacter('abacabaabacaba'));
```

I do not understand how the above solution is O(1) space.  Since we are iterating through our array we are mapping each element to an object (duplicate).  I would think this would be considered O(n), could somebody clarify how this is O(1) for me.   Thanks.

Comment: Who told you it's O(1)? That's clearly wrong if *n* is the length of the string. It's also O(n) in time complexity.

Comment: Consider a string consisting of the first 1000 Unicode characters. How many objects will be created to keep track of the counts? 1000.  It's not O(1).

Comment: They say **uses O(1) additional memory** not O(1) space.

Comment: @KoshVery still incorrect. The amount of additional memory is linearly proportional to the number of distinct characters in the input string. In the worst case, every input character is distinct, and so one object is created per input character. That's O(n).

Comment: A (very questionable) argument could be made that in the limiting case of an input string in the billions of characters, the amount of extra space will never be more than the total possible number of UTF-16 code points, but in practical terms that's pretty ridiculous.

Comment: @Pointy, please read the task carefully =))

Comment: @KoshVery I have read it over. Please offer an explanation of how the case of one additional object per distinct input character is O(1).

Comment: @Pointy, they need **first Not Repeating Character**

Comment: @KoshVery have you actually looked at the code? It creates another object for each distinct input character.

Comment: @KoshVery Doesn't really matter what the question asks, that first `forEach` is going through the entire array and creating an object for every single unique character. An array of `1000` unique characters creates `1000` objects.

Comment: @Pointy That unicode code point argument is exactly the correct argument for why this is O(1). Big-O notation refers to the asymptotic complexity with a corresponding mathematical definition. Since there exists a constant M that is greater than the memory usage for *any* input size, we say the asymptotic complexity of the space usage is in the O(1) class.

Comment: @JaredGoguen I agree with that in an academic sense, but that result is for most practical purposes uninteresting. You may very well be correct however that that is exactly what the (still mysterious) source of information driving the question in the first place was based upon.

Comment: @JaredGoguen By that same rationale, if you were to loop through an array and create a new variable for each and every item, would JavaScript's maximum array length of 4.29 billion elements mean that the function is `O(1)`? Not being facetious.

Comment: @Tyler It doesn't matter how many items are created, it matters how the number of items *scales* with the input size. In your example, the number of items clearly scales linearly with the input size.

Comment: @JaredGoguen uhh did you really mean *linearly*?

Comment: @JaredGoguen It would seem to me that OP's example scales with input size up to a maximum of the amount of unicode characters, whereas mine scales with input size up to the max length of a JS array, no?

Comment: @Tyler It is not clear what *n* is in your example. But, yes, your memory usage could be O(1) if *n* is independent of the number of items created.

Comment: Why is the finiteness of Unicode of interest when considering the abstract complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: I guess it boils down to an Aleph 0 vs Aleph 1 issue :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory usage is proportion to the number of distinct characters in the string. The number of distinct characters  has an upper limit of 52 (or some other *finite* value) and the potential memory usage does not increase as *n* increases once each of the distinct characters has been seen.

Thus, there exists an upper limit on the memory usage that is constant (does not depend on *n*), so the memory usage is O(1).

Comment: UTF-16 has tens of thousands of characters.

Comment: As long as it's finite, the argument holds.

Comment: Thanks Pointy you make a good point and so does Jared.  In this instance I think we might assume it is only english letters, and if that is the case it makes sense why it would be O(1) space and not O(n) space.  Thanks Jared.

Comment: @checkingJS right. If the problem were generalized and the input was a list of some type with a less tightly bounded set of values (say, numbers), the academic argument might still hold but to me it would make even less practical sense.

Comment: @checkingJS The point holds so long as the number of characters in the set is finite. We are interested in how the memory usage scales with the input size in the *asymptotic* case -- this case is, generally speaking, not the "reasonable case."

Comment: To be abstract and independent of implementation realities, one could argue that a "string" is a "list of glyphs". The set of possible glyphs is arguably infinite.

Comment: To put that another way, it seems strange to say that the limit on the number of possible characters *does* matter, but the practical limit on the length of a string does *not* matter means that the abstract algorithmic behavior analysis is not really abstract. Why should the number of possible glyphs available for inclusion in a string of them be finite?

Comment: Let G be the set of glyphs in question and let f(n) be a function which gives the memory usage of the program based on the input size. If |G| is finite then there exists a real positive number M such that M > f(n) for all n. This is the definition of O(1). If |G| is not finite, then it could be that no such M exists. Or, maybe there is a different way to frame the problem which deals with an infinite |G|... either way, the argument becomes more difficult and is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @JaredGoguen yes I think I've convinced myself that even in the face of a massively large potential set of characters, an unbounded list of them is always "more unbounded".

Comment: @Pointy That's a deep and possibly unresolved question -- mathematicians generally look at the cardinality of infinite sets based on whether it is possible to create a 1-to-1 mapping between the sets. However, the collection of strings made up of a set of glyphs is certainly larger than the powerset of the glyphs and the continuum hypothesis would suggest that these two sets do not have the same cardinality. I'm not really a mathematician however, and I would take my opinion on these matters with a grain of salt.

Comment: @JaredGoguen yes that's exactly what I mean (but I'm no mathematician) — to my limited mind it seems like the difference between the infinity of integers and the infinity of real numbers, kind-of. As a practical day-to-day programmer however I would still consider the OP code to be O(n), because my software at least rarely encounters billion-character strings :)

Comment: @Pointy To resolve the discussion, Cantor's theorem proves that these two sets do not have the same cardinality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: @JaredGoguen right I know that and that's why I decided to agree with you :)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm has **O(min(a,n))** space complexity (where **a** is number of letters used for text cooding e.g. for UTF8 **a>1M**). For worst case: string with uniqe characters (in this case **n<=a**)  e.g. `abcdefgh`  the `duplicates` object has the same number of keys as number letters of input string - and what is clear on this case, the size of used memory depends on **n**.

The **O(1)** is only for case when string contains one repeated letter e.g. `aaaaaaa`.

**Bonus**: Your code can be "compressed" in this way :)

```js
function firstNotRepeatingCharacters(s, d={}, r="_") {  
  for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++) d[s[i]]=++d[s[i]]|0;  
  for(let i=s.length-1; i>=0; i--) if(!d[s[i]]) r=s[i];  
  return r;
}

console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacters('abacabad'));
console.log(firstNotRepeatingCharacters('abacabaabacaba'));
```

Comment: I would be rooting for you up until a few minutes ago, and I still think that in *practical* day-to-day programming terms this is "correct", or at least the useful way of thinking about it.

Comment: @Pointy I a little change my answer - in real-life the **O(n)** is misleading, but  **O(min(a,n))** reveals space complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is an 0(1) complexity, but only on space constraints. Since we have an upper limit. This limit could be UTF-16, it could be the amount of English letters.

This is a constraint given by the Developer. Saying that, it's only a 0(1) in space constraints if the code above ran with a finite set of combinations.

A String it's limited by implementation to a 64 bit character "array". So the store capacity generally of a "String" type it's 2147483647 (2ˆ31 - 1) characters. That's not really what 0(1) represents. So virtually that's an 0(N) in space constraints.

Now the situation here it's totally different for time complexity constraints. It should be in the optimal scenario a 0(N) + 0(N - E) + 0(N).

Explaining:
1. First 0(N) the first loop goes through all the elements
2. Second 0(N) is about the deletion. The code delete's element's from the array.
3. 0(N - E) the second forEach loops the final popped array, so we have a constant E.

And that's supposing that the data structure is an Array.

There's a lot to Digg here.

TL;DR

It's not a 0(1).